# CATransform3D not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, catransform3d

CATransform3D not working properly, I am using the below code. My problem is If I change the transform Its working fine. Once I release my finger and then make more transform the image  goes to the Initial image. How to set the last transform? I am using PanGesture for the transform. Please give some Idea. Thanks in advance.

```
if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(translationInView:)]) {
    CGPoint translation = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view.superview];
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, translation.x * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -translation.y * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CATransform3DIdentity` means you resetting the transformation every time your view receives touch. Use `CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = layer.transform;` instead.